# File read time in c increase unexpectedly

Tags: performance, time, fread, solid-state-drive

I'm currently facing an annoying problem, I have to read a big data file (500 GO) which is stored on a SSD revodrive 350.

I read the file using fread function as big memory chunks (roughly 17 mo per chunk).

At the beginning of my program everything goes smoothly It takes 10ms for 3 chunks read. Then after 10 sec read time performances collapse and vary between 60 and  90 ms.

I don't know the reason why this is happening and if it is possible to keep read time stable ?

Thank you in advance

Rob

Answer (score -1):

> 17 mo per chunk, 10 ms for 3 chunks -> 51 mo / 10 ms.

**10 sec = 1000 x 10 ms -> 51 GO read after 10 seconds!**

How much memory do you have? Is your pagefile on the same disk?

The system may swap memory!